# Migrating 10.0 map services to ArcGIS 10.2 for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I have a few map services that I would like to move to ArcGIS for Server 10.2.  Each server is on a separate machine.  I have come across instances where people migrate the entire arcgisserver folder, (arcgisinput, arcgisoutput, cache, etc.) however my 10.0 services only maintain an input and an output.

What's the most time efficient manner in migrating single map services and not an entire instance from 10.0-10.2?

Comment: Good question. Why would you need to preserve the input and output though? In 10.2, you'd need to republish services anyway, so the whole folder with metadata services will be created from scratch. Output is only for temporal images generated when serving the map requests from the GIS server, you don't need them when you've moved your map service to another machine. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Not entirely sure, this might have been from one 10.1 machine to another.  I think the best way to go is to republish the services entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this from 10.0 to 10.2 for single services are to copy map packages and create new service definitions then publish.